# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geometry, postgis

I need to find out the users in certain distance from a latitude and longitude.

```
organisation.users.joins(:location)
            .where("ST_DWithin(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(locations.longitude locations.latitude)', 4326),ST_GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)', 4326), ?)", longitude, latitude, distance)
            .pluck(:id)
```

I am getting this error 
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry`

Comment: You miss comma: `point(locations.longitde, locations.latitude)`, though I'm not sure if it's this.

Comment: @Aarthi could you please share the content of these variables: `locations.longitude locations.latitude`? I'd guess that the decimal values are separated by `,` comma, which will indeed generate an error. Try using `.` point as a decimal separator

Comment: @MarekLipka are you sure WKT Points need a comma to split _x_ and _y_?

Comment: @JimJones I'm not, it's true it's only guess based on documentation here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-geometry.html
But I can be wrong.

Comment: locations.latitude and locations.longitude are float values

Comment: @Aarthi are the decimals of these float values separated by comma or point? Right -> `POINT(1.1 1.2)`  wrong -> `POINT(1,1 1,2)`

Comment: @MarekLipka you're mixing parameters for geometric functions with wkt literals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text (surprisingly, at wikipedia the standard is better documented than in the OGC docs)

Comment: @JimJones those will be floats, that will be POINT(1.1 1.2) right,  and it shows HINT:  "POINT(la" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry

Comment: Strange. If your code is indeed creating a literal like `POINT(1.1 1.2)` there is no way on earth it can be the problem. Just to be on the safe side, can you show an output of the created wkt literals before they are placed in your SQL? Just to see what is being generated.

Comment: @JimJones this is the location object, `#<Location id: 80, user_id: 284, latitude: 6.221, longitude: 11.22112, created_at: "2018-05-08 10:00:43", updated_at: "2018-05-08 10:00:43", captured_at: "2018-05-08 10:00:43", deleted_at: nil>`

Comment: Well, if your code isn't somehow messing the variables, it should generate this wkt: `POINT(11.22112 6.221)` which will give you a point somewhere in Cameroon. Make sure these values are indeed getting to the variables you're using to build the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to column names inside a string, so this string is used instead of the intended coordinates.

To overcome this, you would need to concatenate the text command (`'point('` with the column values and at last you concatenante the end of the text command (`')'`). As a result, the column name is not within the single quotes anymore.

```
organisation.users.joins(:location)
            .where("ST_DWithin(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || locations.longitude  || ' ' ||  locations.latitude ||')', 4326),ST_GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)', 4326), ?)", longitude, latitude, distance)
            .pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Can I get the reference for this, I have never seen this operator before

Comment: @Aarthi it is used to concatenate strings, so you are now building a string using the column content. See the operator doc [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)